# Height 100% minus the top navigation

Tags: css

I have a site that has a top navigation bar, a header, a sidebar and a content body next to the sidebar. The header, sidebar, and content body are positioned absolutely so that they don't move when you navigate to other pages that are using the same template. The sidebar and content body have scroll bars. The header and sidebar are always visible even with scrolling. This works great as shown in the demo. But suppose the top navigation changes height. Then the vertical alignment is off. Since this site is using a global top navigation that's used in other sites as well, the top navigation can change at any moment. When it does change, this layout will not be future proof. Is there a way to make this future proof?

What I have currently:
http://codepen.io/codingninja/pen/nKwox

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}  
.content {
    /*position: relative;*/
}
.top-nav {
    background: #000;
    height: 42px;
    color: #fff;
}
.header{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ddd;
}
.sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 142px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #aaa;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 100px;
}
.body {
    position: absolute;
    top: 142px;
    right: 0;
    left: 150px;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

What happens when the top nav changes height:
http://codepen.io/codingninja/pen/nICzK

```
.top-nav {
    background: #000;
    height: 100px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you chose to position everything absolute ?

Comment: I need the sidebar and header to stay visible as you scroll. Is there a better way to make this work?

Comment: It is better to use `position: fixed` to keep the header and sidebar visible when you scroll. However like `position: absolute` it takes the content out of the normal document flow which is why you needed to position the content with a fixed number in the first place. I guess `position: sticky` might be used to solve this in the future (as it's only supported on Firefox).

Comment: Position: fixed would not be good because when you scroll horizontally, it will look messed up. Also on mobile devices it will also look messed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of absolutely positioning everything you can make use of `display:table` to achieve the layout you want.  Using the following html

```
<div class="table">
    <div id="top-nav" class="row">
        <div class="cell">top-nav</div>
    </div>
    <div id="header" class="row">
        <div class="cell">header</div>
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="row">
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="table">
                <div id="side-bar" class="cell">     
                    <div class="overflow">
                        sidebar
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="body-content" class="cell">
                    <div class="overflow">body-content</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And Css

```
html, 
body, 
.table {height:100%; padding:0; margin:0;}

.table {display:table; width:100%;}
.table .row {display:table-row;}
.table .cell {display:table-cell;}

#top-nav {height:42px;}
#header  {height:100px;}
#content  {height:100%;}

#side-bar {width:100px;}

.overflow {height:100%; overflow:auto;}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/03k96ebk/2/)

You will notice that when your top nav grows, your main content area will shrink.  You will also not get into a positioning / z-index nightmare

Comment: Actually, this may be problematic since I can't put the topnav into the table structure. I only have control over everything after the topnav. :( Is there another way to go about this perhaps?

Comment: I think you may need to use a bit of js then if you are unable to change the code layout as there would be no other way of calculating the height of the top nav - ah as you have answered

Comment: Right. I wrote below a JavaScript solution that worked for me. Thanks Pete.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean this:
Css3 has a [Calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) Function

```
Height: Calc( 100% - 100px )
```

Comment: Thanks Goosebumbs. I don't want to do that since I would have to set a height 100px. I would like a way to make it so it doesn't matter what the height of the black navigation bar is as it could change. The black navigation is global throughout a series of many websites including this site. We've already changed the black navigation once since I started working.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that involves a line of javascript to set top to the calculated height based on the height of the top nav and the header.

```
$(".sidebar, .body").css('top', topnavheight+100);
```